# How can I disable the automatic switch to "library" mode in Windows Media Player 12?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, sync, windows-media-player

Whenever I plug any USB device into my computer while running **Windows Media Player 12** in **Windows 7** or later, it will automatically swtich the player from the Now Playing mode to Library mode. This is intended to faciliate syncing between Media Player and MP3 players, but it happens for *any* USB device.

I'd like this to not happen since it's infuriating to see this take place while I'm watching something on a separate screen in Media Player just from plugging in a USB key.

This has nothing to do with Windows autorun, and nothing to do with versions of Windows pre-7.

And no, switching to some other video player is not an option; I've tried them all, none are as good as stock Media Player.

Comment: I get exactly the same problem with Media Player in Vista, if I plug my phone or PSP or whatever in to charge while I'm watching a movie it swaps to the library mode and offers to sync. Interested to hear if an answer to this question would work for me too.

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but I just disable the Portable Device Enumerator Service.

Answer (score 2):

According to this recent question [Stop Windows Media Player showing synchronization dialogue when USB device plugged](https://superuser.com/questions/52141/stop-windows-media-player-showing-synchronization-dialogue-when-usb-device-plugge) the trick is to let it partially sync so that you get the WMPInfo.xml file created on your device (and leave it there), you can then go into WMP's options and your device will be listed along with the options uncheck "Start sync when device connects".

The questioner was asking about WMP11 on XP, but I've confirmed that this also works with WMP11 on Vista. Haven't had a chance to try it on my Win7 machine at home yet, but it does look very likely to work.

Comment: This trick doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 on WMP12.

Comment: This does not work reliably on WMP on Windows 10. For a cleaner solution see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for WMP 12 on all Windows versions:

- Close WMP and open Services
- Find `Portable Device Enumerator Service`. In the registry, you'll find this at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WPDBusEnum`.
- If running, stop the service
- Set `Startup type` to `Disabled`. In the registry, you would set `...\Services\WPDBusEnum\Start` to `4`.
- Close Services and re-open WMP

The infuriating "feature" has been disabled...enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Ever tried to set the Autorun settings for your USB device?

In Windows XP it would be like this:

**How to Disable USB Drive to autorun (Windows XP):**

- Open Windows Explorer or press the Windows + “e” key.
- Right-click the drive of the USB Drive.
- Then select Properties. Drive Properties will appear.
- Select the AutoPlay tab.
- Choose Select an Action to Perform
- At the bottom of the selection, click Take no Action, then click Apply.
- Click OK to exit Drive Properties.

If you don't think that will work go to the [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715/)
[It will help you tweak your](http://techasylum.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-disable-autoplay-of-usb-drives.html) register to [disable Auto-Run completely](http://features.engadget.com/2004/06/29/how-to-tuesday-disable-autorun-on-windows/) for certain devices.

Type gpedit.msc in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER to open the Group Policy Editor.

Under Computer Configuration > expand Administrative Templates > expand Windows Components > click Autoplay Policies.

In the RHS Details pane, double-click Turn off Autoplay to open the Properties box.
Click Enabled, and then select All drives in the Turn off Autoplay on box to disable Autorun on all drives.

Restart.

**Additional Read:**

How to selectively disable specific Autorun features and more on KB953252.

You can also open the Control Panel

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > AutoPlay
and set the options as per your preferences.

3) The same can be achieved by editing the Registry.
Run regedit and navigate to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

In the RHS, create a new dword and rename it to NoDriveTypeAutoRun.

Rt click on it and give it a decimal value 225 (or Hexadecimal value 000000FF) Exit regedit.

Reboot.

This will disable AutoRun on all drives

Comment: i suggested this and he bit my head off, watch out =O

Comment: Haha, Bite me :P

Comment: It's a Media Player 12 issue in 7, not a Windows issue. Changing the autorun has no effect -- it's the first thing I tried months ago when this started bugging me. This has nothing to do with Autorun, nor Windows XP for that matter -- WMP12 isn't even available on XP.

Comment: You do understand that if it happens when you plug something in Auto-run is the first thing to suspect? Plus XP did have a different version of WMP which might have that problem

Answer (score -1):

right click on playlist toolbar, go to tools, then click options. on player settings in player tab, click the 'keep Now Playing on top of other windows'.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using windows 7. Do the following.

1. Open Windows Registry
2. Head to 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
3. Then to 'SOFTWAFRE'
4. Next 'MICROSOFT'
5. Look for 'Windows Device Manger', click it
6. On the Right see a registry by the name '(Default)'?
7. Double click it
8. Enter the value '0'
9. Hit enter and then exit

Totally Works. Keeps your Autoplay option, but Player no longer switches screens :D

And if it in any case doesn't work, try the same with a flash drive plugged in.