# Stop Windows Media Player showing synchronization dialogue when USB device plugged

Tags: windows, usb, windows-media-player, sync

Every time I plug a USB stick into my PC, I get this synchronization dialogue in WMP. It's really annoying, and it also stops my Play/Pause shortcut keys working.

This is really starting to annoy me.

I've found [one link](http://forums.hexus.net/operating-systems-applications/171613-i-never-want-sync-my-device-windows-media-player-issue.html) which mentions this problem and possible solutions, including a registry hack, but without giving details.

Is anyone else bothered by this, and has anyone found a solution?

**EDIT** OK, after reading [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsmedia.player/browse_thread/thread/0412de7523ad083b) and [here](http://discuss.extremetech.com/forums/thread/1004396293.aspx), I fiddled round a bit, ended up synchronising just one file, and then when I next inserted the USB stick, no more popup... Not great, but better.

Comment: Which version of Windows Media Player do you have?

Comment: @Dave 11 on XP            .

Answer (score 3):

Disable and stop service **WPDBusEnum** aka Portable Device Enumerator Service

Comment: hm, can't find it (searched in registry just to be sure), does this apply for XP? I found WmdmPmSN. Problem is that my OS is in French, so the display names aren't the same.

Comment: The short service names should be the same for all language versions of windows, it's just the friendly names that get translated. Try running `net stop WPDBusEnum` at a command prompt to see if it's installed. You can then use this to disable it `sc config WPDBusEnum start= disabled`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your feedback, I haven't got that service running on my machine apparently.

Answer (score 2):

First advice to try (doesn't work on my WMP11):

> tools --> option --> Devices tab --> select the device (flash drive with mp3 player icon) then click
>   properties --> Sync tab --> uncheck
>   "Start sync when device connects"

If this doesn't apply, try this:

You have to go through with the the sync just once. Then the option to "Start sync when device connects" will no longer be grayed out.
WMP will have now made a file on your flash drive "WMPInfo.xml".
You have to keep this file on the drive, otherwise you will be asked to sync again. You can delete any other files that were put on the drive from the sync.
This only works for the machine where you performed the snyc. If you do it on another machine, it will overwrite "WMPInfo.xml" and you will be back to square one.

Comment: Yup, "Start sync when device connects" is greyed out for me

Comment: OK, so let it sync, and the next time it won't be grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Start menu, choose Control Panel.
2. Select `Default Programs`.
3. Click `Change AutoPlay settings`.
4. Chose the device and select `Take No Action`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Default programs when you type in a search on the Windows 10 Start Menu' search. There is only Default APPs and no Change Autoplay Settings does not exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).